# How to read X and Y Coordinates of Error Series in Teechart .net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, teechart

[image]

How to read y coordinates of error series in teechart? I want Upper and lower coordinates of y axis when cursor moves on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a TeeChart mouse event (eg.: OnMouseMove) and series' Clicked method to know which point is under the mouse and retrieve corresponding values as in this example:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      InitializeChart();
    }

    private void InitializeChart()
    {
      tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
      tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error()).FillSampleValues();
      tChart1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tChart1_MouseMove);
    }

    void tChart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error error1 = (Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error)tChart1[0];

      int index = error1.Clicked(e.X, e.Y);
      string tmp = "";

      if (index != -1)
      {
        double y = error1.YValues[index];
        double error = error1.ErrorValues[index];
        double top = y + error;
        double bottom = y - error;
        tmp = top.ToString("#.##") + " - " + bottom.ToString("#.##");
      }
      else
      {
        tmp = "";
      }

      this.Text = tmp;
    }
  }
```

If you use a CursorTool there are e.XValue and e.YValue arguments which give you the axes values of the CursorTool and e.x and e.y which are the equivalent of MouseMove e.X and e.Y arguments so you can do the same as with that event, a simple example:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  InitializeChart();
}

private void InitializeChart()
{
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error()).FillSampleValues();
  //tChart1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tChart1_MouseMove);

  Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool cursor1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorTool(tChart1.Chart);
  cursor1.Series = tChart1[0];
  cursor1.FollowMouse = true;
  cursor1.Change += new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventHandler(cursor1_Change);
}

void cursor1_Change(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Tools.CursorChangeEventArgs e)
{      
  Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error error1 = (Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error)tChart1[0];

  int index = error1.Clicked(e.x, e.y);
  string tmp = "";

  if (index != -1)
  {
    double y = error1.YValues[index];
    double error = error1.ErrorValues[index];
    double top = y + error;
    double bottom = y - error;
    tmp = "Error top: " + top.ToString("#.##") + 
          " Error bottom: " + bottom.ToString("#.##") +
          " Cursor pos.: " + e.XValue.ToString("#.##") + "/" + e.YValue.ToString("#.##");
  }
  else
  {
    tmp = "";
  }

  this.Text = tmp;
}
```

Comment: error1.Clicked(int, int); My series has records 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 then how to get index?

Comment: error1.Clicked returns such values? It should return integers from 0 to error1.Count-1. If the problem persists please post it at http://www.teechart.net/support/index.php with a test case or, if you are not a TeeChart registered customer, send your example project at http://www.steema.net/upload/.

Comment: @ Narcis Calvet Can you told me how to handle it in case of cursortool as cursor tool has other CursorChangeEventArgs and it is work only if we place mouse cursor on Errorseries. How to solve it for cursorTool. Thanks

Comment: @AbhijitShelar sure, see my answer, just extended it to include CursorTool.

Comment: @ Narcis Calvet Yes it is working but I want to display values in textbox only if cursortool line is on that line. With your code it works but continuously updates textbox.

Comment: @AbhijitShelar Ok, CursorTool code updated. It's very similar to what I did for the mouse position.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with teechart but I'm pretty sure there  is a cursor.move event if not you can create one.
Then modify that event to catch cursor.position like so

```
CursorMove(object sender, args e)
{

   this.lowerTextBox.value = cursor.postion;

}
```